# Zabbix returns no data when doing DNS check with default DNS resolver

Tags: dns, zabbix

I'm trying to build an item for a Zabbix 3.4 template to perform DNS checks. Based on the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) I should be using `net.dns[<ip>,name,<type>,<timeout>,<count>,<protocol>]`. If I specify an external DNS resolver such as Google or OpenDNS I get the expected return of 1.

However, when I remove the resolver IP and allow it to use default I get no data returned. The same happens when I manually specify the IP address in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Please show item key that work as you expect and one that doesn't. How are you testing them?

Comment: `net.dns[208.67.222.222,domain.com,2,1]` works and returns 1 as expected. `net.dns[domain.com,2,1]` returns "No data". As for testing, I have a graph that returns the output either 1 or 0 is the service is up or down. However, in this case (without specifying DNS resolver) it returns No Data and the graph is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is wrong.
Try using this :

```
net.dns[,domain.com,2,1]
```

Removing the first argument does not mean to remove the comma ;)